# How to stop JSON Path returning object

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I'm having an issue with JSONPath work. I have two very similar json objects that I am trying to get values from.

Essentially the objects roughly look like this:

```
Object1: {Company: {Organisation: {Official Name: "Name"}}
jsonpath1: Company..Organisation..Official Name
```

```
Object2: {Company: {Organisation:"Name"}}
jsonpath2: Company..Organisation
```

My issue is that I need both of these paths running. For Object2, this causes no issue as the first jsonpath doesn't return anything.

For object1 however, jsonpath 1 returns the required value. However, for this record jsonpath2 also returns the value Object object.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? I require both json paths. They both return the name of the company but unfortunately the data structure has changed - hence the issue

Comment: Your object code is not valid JSON. Your jsonpath samples are not valid jsonpaths.

Comment: Hence the word roughly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), then a solution to the problem of writing a query that will retrieve the company name is very simple:

```
.Company.Organisation | if type == "string" then . else ."Official Name" end
```

#### Example

For example, if company.json contains the lines:

```
{"Company": {"Organisation": {"Official Name": "Name1"}}}
{"Company": {"Organisation": "Name2"}}
```

then the result of running

```
jq '.Company.Organisation | if type == "string" then . else ."Official Name" end' company.json
```

would be:

```
"Name1"
"Name2"
```

(If you want the names without the outer quotation marks, you could run jq with the -r command-line option.)